# Radixx API example

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using radixx API for flight search and booking. They gave me the WSDL links and [SDK](http://connectpoint.radixx.com/sdk/) for the WSDL:
Here are the WSDL files:-

```
http://s9.tpapi.uat.radixx.com/
```

I have tried one:-

http://s9.tpapi.uat.radixx.com/RadixxSecurity.asmx?op=GetSecurityGUID

I have given the loginid and password and got the guid.
But when i am trying other WSDL file to get details Like below:-

http://s9.tpapi.uat.radixx.com/RadixxFlights.asmx?op=GetFlightScheduleInformation_v2

Here there are five parameter but i know only three of these :-
SecurityGUID(Got from the above wsdl)
StartSearchDate and EndSearchDate(These are the dates)

I dont't know about :-
SearchType and SearchCriteria

They told me i can get those value from SDk but i can't find those.

I cant find the values of other wsdl parameters. Please help me to get those parameters values.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: could you share some demo details to invoke..

Comment: Hi, where you ever able to figure out how to integrate their APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK manual you've been given is not matching the WSDL API. The operation you're looking for should be on http://connectpoint.radixx.com/sdk/#Flight%20-%20Request_xsd.html, but it's not documented. You'll have to contact them for a more complete documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have asked them many times and just told me one thing "Follow the SDK".

Comment: That's too bad, look's like they just don't want to help you. Do you know other websites that use this API? Maybe they can point you into the right direction?

Comment: yes i know they are :- http://www.flyafricaworld.com/,http://www.flystarbow.com/..

Comment: The web builders of those websites are dothouseghana.com (first one) and acsghana.com (second one), maybe they can help you?